# In a 2-D array, how can I change/access the position of the diagonal characters?

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have a nested list of 1's as follows:

```
rows = 8*"1".split()
nested_list = []

for i in range(8):
    nested_list.append(rows)
```

The above produces
`nested_list = [[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]....x8]]`

And I would like to change every other 1 to -1;

i.e I want the **output** to look like this: `[[-1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,1],...]` - I hope you can see what is happening.

Here is my code to try and achieve this:

```
for i in range(len(nested_list)): 
    for j in range(i,len(nested_list)): 
        nested_list[i][i] = "-1" 
        break
```

However, this produces `[[-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1],[-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1],...x8]]`
But I don't understand why?
My logic for the above code is that `'i' will iterate from 0 to 7`; and **for each iteration**, `j will be equal to 'i'` and we then change the position `nested_list[I][i] to -1`, i.e. `nested_list[1][1]`, then `nested_list[2][2]`, then `nested_list[3][3]`,..., `nested_list[8][8]`, which is the `diagonals` of the 2-D array? Where is my logic incorrect?? Thanks!

Comment: You are appending the same list  reference - not individual lists. Same data, same ref 8 times

Comment: `nested = [ [1 for _ in range(8)] for _ in range(8)]`  + `for i in range(8): nested[i][i] = 42`

Comment: To do somethings in a quadratic 2d array you would only need to iterade 1 dim - you never use `j` so why create it?! Also remove the break after going down to 1 dim iteration

Comment: Hi Patrick, apologies I am quite new to this. I can't understand what changes I need to make to my code to make it work as desired. I understand your point about not using the 'j' and I see that I am appending the same list reference; is this what is causing the issue? Because as I change this list reference all of the appends change?

Comment: I got it, never mind. Thanks for answer